# how to declare pageSize in axios get api for pagination vue 3 while it has the data

Tags: vue.js, axios, pagination, vuejs3

I'm using Tailwind Pagination for my vue app. I'm currently getting all the data from axios get, and it also gets `page: 1` and `pageSize: 200` from api.
[image]
but they've told me that I have to send the numbers myself and I'm stuck in the middle of it...
I'm getting data like:

in Employee page:
async getUser() {
await this.$store.dispatch("axiosGet", {url: 'identity/api/employees'}).then(response => {
if (response.status === 'error') return
this.userList = response.data.data.data
this.page = response.data.data.page
this.pageSize = response.data.data.pageSize
this.totalCount = response.data.data.totalCount
console.log(response.data.data)
})
},

and then, in Tailwind component passed data through:

in Table component:

then, inside the VPagination component it's what's happening:

```
<VueTailwindPagination
:current="page"
  :total="totalCount"
  :per-page="pageSize"
  @page-changed="pageChange($event)">
  </VueTailwindPagination>
```

then:

```
props: {
userList: {type: Object},
page: {type: Number},
pageSize: {type: Number},
totalCount: {type: Number}
},
```

methods:

```
pageChange(pageNumber) {
  this.currentPage= pageNumber
},
```

so, there's only one page and no pagination is possible.

[image]

the Swagger is like this:
[image]

Can anyone help me with the problem?

Comment: I guess the problem is `pageSize`, when you have a pageSize of 200 and total count is 37, obviously there isn't next page to create pagination, am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly. but I get it from api and they've told me I've got to give it my value so it will paginate. is it even possible whent it's a get? and if yes, I'm wondering how..

Comment: yes they are right, you need to pass the pageSize as a query string param to their API, but of course you need to ask them how should pass this param, in some endpoints you can pass as `page_size` but in others are different

Comment: so i need to send params ad props in the component? cuz the data table is rendered in my employee page, and there's pagination component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your data like this:

```
async getUser() {
 await this.$store.dispatch("axiosGet",
 {url: `identity/api/employees?page=${1}&pageSize=${10}`})
 .then(response => {})
},
```

but you need to replace the constant value with your local variables...

Comment: ok, I've set the page size as how it's needed. but for page, should I make a function righ? a function like, when I click nex it'll be like page+1 for example. but it needs to be done in the component and I'm getting api before rendering component

Comment: for page variable you can do like this, when the page is loaded for the first time the page has the default value of 1 right? after that when a user clicks on the next page you can make three approaches: 1- bind your value to the component with the `.sync` directive or send an event to child component to change its value or call the component function with `$refs`

Comment: ummm like here:
`<VueTailwindPagination v-model="this.$props.page"
  :current="page"
  :total="totalCount"
  :per-page="pageSize"
  @page-changed="pageChange($event)">
  </VueTailwindPagination>

I need to get $event to change page.`

Comment: No, I thought you mean you wrapped this component to another component but as you can see this component accepts the `v-model` directive and it's enough for it, you should declare a variable in your main component `currentPage` and just bind it to this v-model:
`<VueTailwindPagination v-model="currentPage"   :current="page"   :total="totalCount"   :per-page="pageSize"   @page-changed="pageChange($event)">   </VueTailwindPagination>`

Comment: I've just updated it... it doesn't get v-model... ;(